# Manual adding firefox for android addon

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon

I've got an firefox add-on, but I want to test before I upload it to the firefox add-on center..

Does anybody know if I can install the add-on (XPI file) on firefox for android?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah this is possible:

- Install firefox app
- Place XPI-file on your android device
- Install good file explorer like: **ES File Explorer File Manager**
- Open XPI with file explorer and choose firefox

Add-on should get installed now.
This should work

**PS:** if file explorer doesn't give option to open with firefox, than choose open with 'other' and select firefox yourself.

Comment: Hi Strider are you an android firefox addon developer? I was planning on using some ctypes and was wondering if you knew by chance what library would contain fullscreen screenshot functionalities?

Comment: @Noitidart srry, i'm not that experienced with firefox addons.